# Feed data to remote process

Tags: php, python, web-hosting, remote-server

I am not really sure how to phrase my question, but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I want to create a demo website which allows people to input sentences which are then sent to a remote host, and classified in a `Python script` on that host. Basically, the Python script, when initialised, needs to load some big classifier files into NLTK classifier objects, which is preferably done only once to save time. So I would like to keep these objects alive. I realise I can execute a `while` loop in order to wait for any incoming data. The loop would parse the data and do whatever with it:

```
#pseudocode for Python script
while True:
    if(some_remote_input){
        parse, classify, etc.;
        }
```

My question: What is a recommended package to collect data sent remotely? `socket`, perhaps?

And how would I go about this in PHP/AJAX? The desired procedure is like this:

1. User enters a sentence in the web app
2. Sentence is validated/prepared
3. **Sentence is sent to remote host as input for python script (which is *always*  running (like a server)**
4. The result of the python classification script is returned to the website
5. Results are formatted and printed to the user

I am concerned about step 3.

I prefer not to integrate the Python environment on the server where the website is hosted, as there is not a lot of free space and it requires a lot of annoying packages.

If you need any more info, please let me know!

Comment: What do you want to do this in? PHP or Python? Pick one!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really intended as a "recommendation" service; Please see [What types of question to avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I have to use Python on the host where all the classification files are. I have to use PHP etc. on the space where the website is hosted. Does that matter?

Comment: Why **must** you use PHP on the host? Python can be used for both.

Comment: With regards to point 3) You'll want to implement some kind of API that a Frontend application (*say written in Javascript*) talks to.

Comment: Regarding using Python on the server-side; It can be quite minimal if you [pick the right web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Comment: So it's worth the (minimal) effort to use the same language (Python) for both ends instead of PHP and Python? Thanks for the link.

Comment: If it were me (*and it isn't*) I'd implement the solution in purely Python and write a daemon/api.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but http is one of the best meanwhile to handle such work.  to beWebsockets can also jump in. Plain Sockets should be your last option

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a message broker or message queue system.

There are several message brokers available:

- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html)
- [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/)
- [AMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html)

This lets you pipe data betwen the message transmitters (web server) and message consumers (the natural language processing pipeline) in a way that is agnostic to what technologies are used in the web server and the NLP-pipeline

Comment: @JamesMills, thank you for that feedback, I have adjusted my answer to be a bit more technology agnostic.